# Minitest - calling a mocked instance method from within another instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mocking, minitest

I've come across some weird behavior in `Minitest::Mock` and can't figure out what's the reason behind it.

Say I have this class A that has a method `b` that calls method `c`:

```rb
class A

  def b
    c
  end

  def c
    1
  end

end
```

I would like to mock the `c` method to return 2 instead of 1:

```rb
require 'minitest/autorun'

a = Minitest::Mock.new(A.new)
a.expect(:c, 2)
```

But for some reason `b` still returns 1:

```
> a.b
=> 1
```

Obviously calling `c` directly will work:

```
> a.c
=> 2
> a.c
MockExpectationError: No more expects available for :c: []
```

Why is the expectation on `c` not being invoked when calling it from within the instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an awesome gem that solves this beautifully:

https://github.com/bogdanvlviv/minitest-mock_expectations

```rb
assert_called a, :c do
  a.b
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how `Minitest::Mock` works; the mock object is a wrapper around the "real" instance of `A`, and defined expectations intercept the method call before it ever gets to that instance. (Other methods, like `b`, with no expectations defined, are forwarded on unaffected -- though they do still pass through the mock.)

When the instance makes method calls internally, they go directly to `self`, not back through the mock wrapper, so they're dispatched normally, with no chance for interception.

---

Comment: Thanks for the response @matthewd! So is there a way for me to stub `c` somehow?
Say I'm trying to test a method of a Rails model which calls `#save`. I'd like to stub `#save` for performance reasons.

Comment: You may want `stub` instead; mock's focus is on expectations, while stub is there to force behaviour into the system under test.

Comment: But I _do_ want to have expectations. My tested method might have some logic where it does or doesn't call the #save method and I want to fail the test accordingly.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that directly, sorry... the best option that comes to mind would be to stub the method with a mock, and that sounds a bit silly just saying it.